# breeze - help starting out

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I am working on a c#/mvc/breeze/angular project in visual studio and I was asked to build entirely new functionality.  Currently, we have a stored procedure set up and it's being used in an entirely different place to pull data and now we are migrating this "worksheet" that uses this stored procedure to this c#/mvc/breeze/angular project.  The stored procedure returns a regular record set - select * from mytable...  it does several complicated things (not just basic querying) to return the records though...

I see in the c#/mvc/breeze/angular project so far, they only use stored procedures two types of ways:  1 way is if the stored procedure is returning a single value and the other way is if it is returning multiple selects   like this :  select * from table1
select * from table2
select * from table3.

My question is:  how should I go about starting my project (adding it to this one...) - can I use the existing stored procedure or is there some way to integrate it with breeze to illiminate the need for the stored procedure...

I see they have  a table styled worksheet set up (with filters) on this c#/mvc/breeze/angular project  and I can't follow it exactly but it does not seem to be hitting a stored proc.  I'm new to the breeze angular stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want breeze to retrieve the data produced by a stored procedure.  Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555684/breeze-js-can-query-a-sql-view-using-breeze/33822915#33822915) help?

In short, you can define the class of the object you will be pulling from your stored procedure:

```
internal class RvRDetail
{
    public string DistrictName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CalendarDate { get; set; }
    public string RevenueCategoryName { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalRepayment { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalRevenue { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller, just run your stored procedure just as you would without breeze:

```
[BreezeController]
public class SeasonlessRvRController : BreezeAbstractApiController
{

    // GET: breeze/SeasonlessRvR/RvRData
    [HttpGet]
    public object RvRData(string districtList="", string showAllPeriods="0")
    {
        var returnData = _dbContextProvider.Context.Database
            .SqlQuery<RvRDetail>("SELECT * from dbo.udf_SeasonlessRvR(@DistrictList, @ShowAllPeriods)",
                            new SqlParameter("@DistrictList", districtList),
                            new SqlParameter("@ShowAllPeriods", showAllPeriods))
            .ToList();
        return returnData;
    }
}
```

Breeze will return in through the entity manager when you query the endpoint

Since breeze will only be returning plain Javascript Objects, you could also do this with a non-breeze api endpoint using $http.

If you want all the bells and whistles (caching, automatic wiring-up to other entities), you will have to create a view and include it in your model like a table, with the appropriate foreign keys and navigation properties defined.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, but how do I do that?  I don't see breeze using stored proc's directly - only classes/models representing tables and mappings/classes representing relationships.  i also see 1 other helper class that uses some very simple select statements directly in the code.    if i code in c# to use my stored procedure, then what about that is breeze?  @beartrums

Comment: @LisaSolomon, Set it up as the example in the linked post. In that example, the class is defined as an internal class and the action is defined in a breeze api controller.  Then I can use standard breeze query techniques on them and access them through the entityManager just by hitting the endpoint `.from('RvRData')`, returning my array of RvRDetail objects.

If you need navigation properties and further integration into the model rather than just the data, then you might need to try and define it as a view, which you can treat exactly like a table in the model.

Comment: Thanks @MayankPatel, I generally try not to repeat the solution, but it makes sense that the original post could disappear.

Comment: @Beartums: rather than copy, consider flagging the question as a duplicate if a solution to another question applies here too.